# how we will cache webservice response in spring?

Tags: spring

In our project we planning to use Java spring framework web service client so just I want to know ,
What are best practices to implement the web service client in spring?
What are performance points need consider while building such client? 
Can we cache web service response in spring ?

Comment: What do you mean by web service – RESTful, or SOAP?

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are aware of implications of caching results (aka having stale data)

your best alternative would be spring great cache abstraction, introduced on Spring 3.1

[Spring Cache Abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)

Have a look there, you can wrap your webservice client calls in a cache method and let spring deal with the caching part for you. 
Nicest part is that you have the freedom to choose your cache provider.